# Anaconda 64 bit on Ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, bit

I want to use the *mlbox* package ([see here](http://mlbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)) which works with a 64-bit version of Python only. But I have a 32 bit version of Ubuntu, can I install a 64-bit python without any problem ?
PS : I've already installed 32-bit anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

No, 64-bit software requires a 64-bit operating system, or at least a 64-bit kernel.

You may be able to run 64-bit Anaconda in a virtualization environment, or you may be able to upgrade just your kernel to 64-bit (seems unlikely to me though). Here are a couple of links with more info:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118343/run-64-bit-app-on-32-bit-system-ubuntu
- https://superuser.com/questions/111975/can-i-run-64-bit-executables-on-a-32-bit-linux

Comment: Thank you @Matthias for your answer.

Comment: Thank you again @Matthias. I've just seen the adds in your comment. Let me take a look at the links.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it won't work, or if it will (which is less likely) it will have bunch of bugs and have some issues. I would not recommend doing it, because it is just a waste of time.
what I recommend you doing is download the Oracle the Virtualbox ([click here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads))
and try running the 64-bit version of your Linux Ubuntu and try running the Python. Basically try doing this whole process through the virtual machine.
Good Luck with your project !!! I hope I helped you.

Comment: Thank you  @Denis ! In fact I'm using virtualbox on windows7 64-bit and I wanted to install a 64-bit Ubuntu, but I have this same problem here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/675251/virtualbox-has-no-64-bit-options. And I have no solution yet. I cannot acces to the Bios in my laptop due to some security mesure.

Comment: Well the problem why you can't run your 64-bit version is because you CPU or your hardware is not powerful enough to run it. In that case I don't really know how to help you.

Comment: If you have 64-bit Windows but can't install a 64-bit virtual machine, your best (only?) option might be to just install 64-bit Anaconda directly in Windows. Then you should be able to install most packages there.